# get data from excel online (office 365)

Tags: r, excel, office365

I'm using a microsoft app (from http://portal.office.com) to translate and stock tweet on an online excel sheet, now I want to read it with R.

The data in excel sheet url `https://myagency-my.sharepoint.com/.../tweet.xlsx`

I tried:

```
library(readxl)
read_excel('//companySharepointSite/project/.../ExcelFilename.xlsx', Sheet1', skip=1)`
```

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048979/accessing-excel-file-from-sharepoint-with-r). It gives:

> ```
> Error in sheets_fun(path) :    Evaluation error: zip file
> ```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165623/read-excel-file-into-r-with-xlconnect-package-from-url) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I believe `read_excel` works only with local files. This might do the trick:

```
library(xlsx)  
library(httr)
url <- 'https://myagency-my.sharepoint.com/.../tweet.xlsx'  
GET(url, write_disk("excel.xlsx", overwrite=TRUE))  
frmData <- read.xlsx("excel.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: hello i get `Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /mingw32/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none` when i'm doing this

Comment: This looks more like *https connect* issue than *excel file reading* issue; I am afraid I can not help with that :(